# references in C++

Tags: c++

Once I read in a statement that

> The language feature that "sealed the
>   deal" to include references is
>   operator overloading.

Why are references needed to effectively support operator overloading?? Any good explanation?

Comment: ...and you read this statement where?

Comment: @James: Sounds like a Stroustrup quote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what Stroustrup said in "The Design and Evolution of C++" (3.7 "references"):

> References were introduced primarily to support operator overloading. ...
>
> C passes every function argument by value, and where passing an object by value would be inefficient or inappropriate the user can pass a pointer . This strategy doesn't work where operator overloading is used. In that case, notational convenience is essential because users cannot be expected to insert address-of operators if the objects are large. For example:
>
> ```
>  a = b - c;
> ```
>
> is acceptable (that is, conventional) notation, but
>
> ```
>  a = &b - &c;
> ```
>
> is not. Anyway, `&b - &c` already has a meaning in C, and I didn't want to change that.

Answer (score 4):

An obvious example would be the typical overload of ">>" as a stream extraction operator. To work as designed, this has to be able to modify both its left- and right-hand arguments. The right has to be modified, because the primary purpose is to read a new value into that variable. The left has to be modified to do things like indicating the current status of the stream.

In theory, you could pass a pointer as the right-hand argument, but to do the same for the left argument would be problematic (e.g. when you chain operators together).

Edit: it becomes more problematic for the left side partly because the basic syntax of overloading is that x@y (where "@" stands for any overloaded operator) means `x.opertor@(y)`. Now, if you change the rules so you somehow turn that `x` into a pointer, you quickly run into another problem: for a pointer, a lot of those operators already have a valid meaning separate from the overload -- e.g., if I translate `x+2` as somehow magically working with a pointer to `x`, then I've produced an expression that already has a meaning completely separate from the overload. To work around that, you could (for example) decide that for this purpose, you'd produce a special kind of pointer that didn't support pointer arithmetic. Then you'd have to deal with `x=y` -- so the special pointer becomes one that you can't modify directly either, and any attempt at assigning to it ends up assigning to whatever it points at instead.

We've only restricted them enough to support two operator overloads, but our "special pointer" is already about 90% of the way to being a reference with a different name...

Comment: please elaborate on the last sentence you wrote... why would it be problematic for the left side?

Comment: Because then you'd have to call it something like: `(&cin)>>&n`, which is obviously ugly.

Comment: @Blindy: not only that, but when you chain operators like: `cin>>x>>y`, the temporary would have to be a pointer -- and (as pointed out in my edit) you'd quickly have to make special rules for the pointers to keep things like `x+y+z` from being (completely allowable) operations on the pointers themselves instead of the object they pointed at.

Answer (score 1):

References constitute a standard means of specifying that the compiler should handle the addresses of objects as though they were objects themselves. This is well-suited to operator overloading because operations usually need to be chained in expressions; to do this with a uniform interface, i.e., entirely by reference, you often would need to take the address of a temporary variable, which is illegal in C++ because pointers make no guarantee about the lifetimes of their referents. References, on the other hand, do. Using references tells the compiler to work a certain kind of very specific magic (with `const` references at least) that preserves the lifetime of the referent.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you're implementing an operator you want to operate directly on the operand -- not a copy of it -- but passing a pointer risks that you could delete the memory inside the operator. (Yes, it would be stupid, but it would be a significant danger nonetheless.) References allow for a convenient way of allowing pointer-like access without the "assignment of responsibility" that passing pointers incurs.

Comment: Of course, there's nothing keeping one from taking the address of the referent and passing that to delete (that would be a very dumb thing to do, I know).

Comment: please elaborate on this part as it's not clear:

assignment of responsibility" that passing pointers incurs.

Comment: @James: As someone once said, "some languages try to keep you from shooting yourself in the foot. C++ will happily load the shotgun and help you aim." :)

Comment: @Alexander: As a general practice -- in no small part because of the existence of references -- when you give a pointer to a function, you are "handing over responsibility" to that function to manage the pointer resource and clean it up when it is no longer necessary. This isn't mandated by any language constructs, and it's not even true in many codebases. But it's considered by many people to be "good practice." If you want to hand over a pointer without responsibility, you use a reference instead. Keeping the two separate makes it more clear who needs to clean up what.